# Java Shift Right

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

So I've got a piece of code that shifts my array order one to the right. How do I make it shift as many times as the user inputs?

```
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  int i;  
  int [] numberArray = {15, 14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
```

Code to output array. here

```
    System.out.println("\n"); 
    System.out.println("How many positions do you want to shift?:");   
    input.nextInt();


    public static void shiftRight(int[] list)
    {
    if (list.length < 2) return;

    int last = list[list.length - 1];

    for(int i = list.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
              list[i] = list[i - 1];
    }
    list[0] = last;
    }
```

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < amt; ++i) shiftRight(list);` What's the problem exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] numberArray = { 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    randomArray(numberArray);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++)
        System.out.print(numberArray[i] + " ");
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("How many positions do you want to shift?:");
    int shiftTimes = input.nextInt();
    input.close();
    for (int i = 0; i < shiftTimes; ++i)
        shiftRight(numberArray);
    for (int j = 0; j < numberArray.length; j++)
        System.out.print(numberArray[j] + " ");

}

public static void randomArray(int[] numberArray) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++) {
        int randomPosition = rnd.nextInt(numberArray.length);
        int a = numberArray[i];
        numberArray[i] = numberArray[randomPosition];
        numberArray[randomPosition] = a;
    }
}

public static void shiftRight(int[] list) {
    if (list.length < 2)
        return;

    int last = list[list.length - 1];

    for (int i = list.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        list[i] = list[i - 1];
    }
    list[0] = last;
}
```

Comment: Now if I wanted to shuffle the numbers in the array randomly. How would I do so?

Comment: Also how do I properly loop it until the user inputs an incorrect input like A

Comment: I updated the code as per your requirement.Please check.

Answer (score 0):

You did it right. Now just Call the Method in a loop:
Change

```
input.nextInt();
```

to

```
int shiftNumber=input.nextInt();
```

Then,

```
for(int i=0;i<shiftNumber;i++)
{
    shiftRight(numberArray);
}
```